# Display the actual attached file not as a link in Drupal 6?

Tags: file-upload, drupal-6

I enabled `File Upload` module in Drupal 6, so if I create a content like `Page`, I would be able to upload a file like an image or a document. I attached an image in the content and when I viewed it, it shows not the image but the link to it. What would I do to display the actual image? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you will get the image path in node-contentType.tpl.php and page.tpl.php. In any of the pages you can display image rather than displaying the image path.

Comment: is there a way that as much as possible I won't be meddling with the code?

Comment: If you use filefield and imagefield module with CCK, then you will get the image directly